# The importance of arguments object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments, javascript-objects

I am very new to arguments object concept in JavaScript and trying to understand the concept from [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

The below example from the doc explains as follows.

```
 function func1(a, b, c) {
      console.log(arguments[0]);
      // expected output: 1

      console.logr(arguments[1]);
      // expected output: 2

     console.log(arguments[2]);
     // expected output: 3
 }

 func1(1, 2, 3);
```

But I am unable to understand the importance of this concept and in which scenario we mostly use such concept?

Excuse me for question format issues as I am typing in mobile.

Comment: Have you seen the "Examples" section of the page? As an example, it's useful when your function accept a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Propably scrolling to [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#Examples) would show better this concept than first snippet in link

Comment: Yes I have seen that. We can read arguments by index position irrespective of no of arguments passed to the function but I never used such concept in my real time projects so just trying to understand in which cases this concept is used

Comment: If you are new to this you may find this youtube very useful: [Arguments Array in JavaScript ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Sw6OUXjHsk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments object is useful in cases you have possibly a variable number of arguments:

```js
function sumAll() {
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    res += arguments[i];
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(sumAll(3)); // 3
console.log(sumAll(3, 4, 5)); // 12
```

However, since ES6, a version of javascript standardized in 2015 ( also called ES2015), you can use the rest parameter syntax to simplify this operation:

```js
function sumAll(...args) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        res += args[i];
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(sumAll(3)); // 3
console.log(sumAll(3, 4, 5)); // 12
```

The arguments object is therefore no longer necessary.

Comment: "...no longer necessary" unless you need to support [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: There is no "rest operator", there is [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). ;-) I don't think using rest parameters is simpler.

Comment: @axnyff thanks for explaining with advanced examples :)

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I edited. However, I don't understand why you say that it's not simpler. Having a magic object is confusing. The fact arguments is not an array often leads to confusing convertion.

Comment: @Axnyff—I was speaking in the context of explaining the arguments object. I guess rest parameters are a good alternative where an arbitrary number of arguments is expected, however it seems more common to accept a values array or options object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function summIt(){
    let result = 0;
    let args = [...arguments];
    
    args.forEach(el => result += el);
      
    return result;
}
    
console.log(summIt(4,7,4,8,9,3,3)); //38
```

OR

```
const summ = (...args) => {
    let result = 0;
    
    Array.from(args).forEach(el => result += el);
      
    return result;
}
    
console.log(summ(4,7,4,8,9,3,3)); //38
```